# how to add Buttons in datagrid view using C# .net

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

How to add buttons in DataGridView using WinForms application in c# .NET?

In this picture, you can see that buttons are add in rows for delete, edit and active columns names. Like that way, I want to add buttons in DataGrid view in WinForms.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click in your datagridview.
2. In pop-up select `Add Column`.
3. In add column pop-up you can choose `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.

[image]

Comment: i got it. but i want to add button image in that column like in the link i provided

Comment: @Anjana thanks for accepting it as answer. For adding image its quite complicated but there is a detailed tutorial here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27146/DataGridView-Image-Button-Cell

Comment: If you want to append image in button then add "DataGridViewImageColumn" from the drop down list.

Comment: @NayanKatkani is this clickable like a button?

Comment: @MidTwo yes it's a clickable button.

Comment: @NayanKatkani thanks for the clarification (y)

Comment: @MidTwo it's my pleasure

Comment: here i add the image in data grid view. but i can't view that [1].image.https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDs5G.png.

Comment: @Anjana it is ungrateful that you didn't accept my answer. In the first place the question is related with this one. anyways thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function which and call it on form load function

```
Public void AddButton()
{
//Add button
DataGridViewButtonColumn EditButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
EditButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
EditButton.DataPropertyName = "btnColumn";
EditButton.Text = "Button Text";
DataGridView_name.Columns.Add(EditButton);
}
```

If you want to add it manually from code